# How to dynamically select which database to be used

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have an executable Jar with a spring project in it .
There is a properties file which supplies variables to the code and will exist in the same directory as the jar. Everything is working fine. In the java code I load the properties file as :

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(new FileInputStream(PROPERTY_FILE_NAME));
```

My datasource in the applicationContext.xml is

```
 <bean id="teDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testDB"/>
    <property name="username" value="t"/>
    <property name="password" value="t"/>
    <property name="initialSize" value="5"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="10"/>
</bean>
```

The hibernate properties is :

```
   <bean id="hibernateProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="properties">
    <props>    
   <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>    
   <!-- <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop> -->
    <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">250</prop>....
```

All the above works both with MySql OR Oracle and changing the dialect (commented prop key below) will do the switch. But now I want to be able to select a database based on a property in the properties file. In my scenario, how can I achieve this ?

Versions :

```
spring - 3.0.5.RELEASE
hibernate - 3.3.2.GA
```

Comment: Check out Spring profiles.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Wouldnt there be any more simpler solution ? Everything is in place for this project, just this ability to switch databases

Comment: Change the properties before starting the application.

Answer (score 2):

You should have somewhere everything which is dependent of the environment in your application (e.g. database configuration, absolute path of the servers, external WebService URLs, etc.).

This could typically be done using a standard Java properties file. You can then load it using a [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.0.M1/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) and uses `${config.myproperty}` style everywhere in your bean configuration where you need to configure something.

At the startup of the application, you have to give it for instance the path to this configuration file, or it can also be present at a default path (convention over configuration).

Comment: So what changes do I need to make in my appcontext.xml. My aim is to let user choose a database from the properties file which will be in the same dir as the executable jar.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure your build with maven, with profiles :

```
<profiles>  
<profile>
            <id>database1</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <filters>
                    <filter>db1.properties</filter>
                </filters>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>database2</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <filters>
                    <filter>db2.properties</filter>
                </filters>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

In db1.properties file you give all the configuration for the first database, and in db2.properties the other one.

For example you can have : 
database.name = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testDB1 in db1.properties
database.name = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testDB2 in db2.properties

And in your applicationContext file you will just put this :
property name="url" value="${database.name}"

Comment: But this does not allow me to pick a database from a property in a properties file, right